# Safari - no space below masonry objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, masonry

I cant seem to figure out why in safari my masonry objects have no space below them.

The site is live here: http://leebollu.co.uk/lb-newsite/blog.html

Also, just another point, on my local server, the site on refresh stacks my masonry boxes, anyone know what this might be?

My html is:

```
<div id="news-block" class="blog-container">

                            <!--blogpost Item-->
                            <article class="js-fadeup-animate blog-block">
                                <div class="blogpost-item-wrap">

                                <div class="blogpost-item">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
                                        <div class="blogpost-hover">
                                            <span>
                                                <a href="single.html">VIEW POST</a>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="blogpost-intro">
                                    <h4>Post 4</h4>
                                    <p>Mus molorpor sam, nustintende eum quo blant vellore, quibus maximodi offic tet, ad que et excepudae sed Mus molorpor sam, nustintende eum quo blant vellore, quibus maximodi offic tet, ad que et excepudae sed</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            </article>
                            <!--blogpost Item-->
</div>
```

my css is:

```
/*Blog-page*/

.blog-container {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}

.blog-block {
    width: 45%;
    height:auto;
    margin-right:5%;    
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.blog-block:nth-child(2n)   {
    margin-right:0%;
}

.blogposts {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-top:0%;
    margin-bottom:4%;
    padding-top:120px;
}

.blog-intro {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.blog-intro h1  {
    margin-bottom:16px;
}

.blog-intro p   {
    margin-right:20px;
    height:20px;
    line-height:14px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;

    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#404453;
    line-height:24px;
    font-weight:300;
}

.blogpost-item-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.blogpost-item  {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.blogpost-item img  {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom:-3px;
    background-image:url('../images/preloader.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
}

.blogpost-hover {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #6cc5fa;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    opacity:0;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
}

.blogpost-item-wrap:hover .blogpost-hover   {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:0.9;

}

.blogpost-hover span    {
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:44%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;

}

.blogpost-hover span p  {
    color:#ffffff;

}

.blogpost-hover span a {
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:500;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
}

.blogpost-hover span a:hover {
    color:#56697f;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.blogpost-intro {
    height:auto;
    width:86%;
    padding:5% 7% 6% 7%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
}

.blogpost-intro p   {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:19px;
}

.blogpost-intro a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#f5f6f7;
}

.blogpost-intro a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#f5f6f7;
}

.blogpost-intro a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#56697f;
}

.blogpost-intro a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#f5f6f7;
}

.date   {
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:14px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```